# Scheduling Powershell and batch jobs to run synchronously

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I have 4 servers on which I need to do some processing.  The processing is in two parts:

1. Run a batch file
2. Run a powershell script

I need the batch files to run simultaneously on all the servers, ideally at precisely the same time. I have currently set up scheduled tasks on all of the servers because we use a network time service so they are in synchronisation.

I then need to run the Powershell scripts one after the other, i.e. when the script on Server1 finishes, the script on Server2 begins, then when it finishes, Server3 begins, etc.  This could be done in the same way as Part 1, i.e. scheduled tasks, however the tasks take massively varying lengths of time to complete.

I want to avoid the scheduled tasks option for the batch files, even though the time is in sync, I would rather have them all kick off from one place.  Finally I need suggestions on how to go about invoking the Powershell scripts in a queue-like manner across different servers. Is this possible?

**Edit 2012-04-11**

With the help of Keith Hill's answer I have managed to get closer to what I need.  It would make sense for me to post my code at this point:

```
# $strServers[0] must correspond to $strFiles[0]
# $strServers[1] must correspond to $strFiles[1]
# etc.
$strServers = @(
    "di-ads-02",
    "di-ads-03", 
    "si-ads-02",
    "vm-ads-02"
);    
$strFiles = @(
    "D:\Utilities\test.ps1",
    "D:\Utilities\test.ps1", 
    "C:\Utilities\test.ps1",
    "D:\Utilities\test.ps1"
);

try 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $strFiles.Count; $i++)
    {
        $job = Invoke-Command -cn $strServers[$i] -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression $strFiles[$i]} -AsJob;
        # Wait for $job to finish for a maximum of 60 minutes
        Wait-Job $job -Timeout 3600;
    }
}
catch 
{
    Write-Host "ERROR : " + $_;
}
```

I get the following output from PowerShell:

```
Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------                  
47              Job47           Failed     False           di-ads-02            Invoke-Expression $str...
49              Job49           Failed     False           di-ads-03            Invoke-Expression $str...
51              Job51           Failed     False           si-ads-02            Invoke-Expression $str...
53              Job53           Failed     False           vm-ads-02            Invoke-Expression $str...
```

It looks to be getting halfway there, but the execution is failing.  First I thought maybe it *was* running but just wasn't reporting back correctly.  I then modified the `test.ps1` script so that it outputs two files (stderr and stdout) when it runs, so as to leave some proof behind.  When I remote onto those servers and run the scripts locally, those files are generated, but doing it as the above script doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can enable PowerShell remoting on the servers, you can orchestrate the execution of the PowerShell script using jobs from one machine e.g.:

```
$servers = 'server1','server2','server3','server4'
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $job = Invoke-Command -cn $server -Filepath c:\myscript.ps1 -AsJob
    Wait-Job $job -Timeout 180 # wait maximum of 3 minutes
}
```

Comment: Does the file referenced by `-FilePath` need to be in the remote directory format, e.g. `\\servername\c$\myscript.ps1`? Or does it understand it as local to the server it's running on?

Comment: I just found the following [here](http://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html): "When you use this parameter, PowerShell converts the contents of the specified script file to a script block, transmits the script block to the remote computer, and runs it the remote computer"

Comment: Is it possible to force it to use a script on the remote machine?

Comment: @a12jun - Sure.  Just use the -ScriptBlock parameter instead of the -FilePath parameter e.g. `$job = Invoke-Command -cn $server -ScriptBlock {C:\myscript.ps1} -AsJob`.  In this case, myscript.ps1 has to be in the same location on each remote machine.  You could also use a network path \\server\share\myscript.ps1.

Comment: thanks, please would you be so kind as to read the update and let me know your thoughts

Comment: @a12jun Don't use `Invoke-Expression` and you need to pass in the filename like so:`Invoke-Command -cn $strServers[$i] -ScriptBlock {param($file) & $file} -Arg $strFiles[$i] -AsJob`.  Remember that the scriptblock is passed to the remote computer to run and it doesn't have access to any of your local variables like $strFiles.  It only has access to the parameters passed into the scriptblock.

Comment: Thanks, that does the job. However a deeper problem surfaced when for 3 of the 4 servers the `Enable-PSRemoting -Force' command failed, with some problem about the WinRM service. That seems off topic for this specific question so will mark as accepted!

Comment: @a12jun Yeah, getting remoting setup & configured correctly is a whole other topic. :-)  When `Enable-PSRemoting` doesn't work, it's a bad day.